# How to initialize a list containing instances from another class?

Tags: python, oop

I'm trying to learn OOP and I can't find out how to initialize a list containing atributes initialized in another class.

```
class Player:

def __init__(self,name,skill_index):
    self.name=name
    self.skill_index=skill_index


class Team:

def __init__(self, playerlist):
    self.playerlist='''Here I need to init a list of instances from Player class'''
    return(playerlist)
```

So if I call it by `print(Team([Player("Player1", [2, 3]), Player("Player2", [3, 1]]))` what should I write after `self.playerlist=` to get the list? Very sorry for poor explanation, I'm a beginner.

Comment: Can't you just save the Team object to a `team` variable then write `team.playerlist`? Is that all you're trying to do?

Comment: You are already passing a list of players in the `playerlist` argument. Why can't you just assign that to `self.playerlist`? Why do you think you need to do anything else?

Comment: Just write `self.playerlist = playerlist` in the constructor, remove the `return` since you can't explicitly return from a constructor, then just write `team.playerlist` to get the list.

Comment: Thank you very much. I understand, sorry for banal mistakes... However, it's still not doing what i need, probably I poorly explained my problem. I wrote `self.playerlist=playerlist` removed `return` then I saved Team object to `team` variable. But when I write `print(team.playerlist)` it still doesn't print that list I need. @Carcigenicate @Daniel Roseman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Completing what you have already coded:

```
...
class Team:
    def __init__(self, playerlist):
        self.playerlist=playerlist

team = Team([Player("Player1", [2, 3])])
player = team.playerlist[0]
print(player.skill_index)
>> [2, 3]
```

To access members of a list, the position is used, starting from 0: `some_list[position]`.
Just remember: `__init__` shall not return ever and everything is an `object` in Python, also lists; you can access properties of an element in a list by using the `.` notation or `getattr` built-in method.

UPDATE: to know the length of an iterable object use `len()`

Comment: Thanks. It is my first OO program, and some things were unclear for me, but now I understand..

Comment: Please, could you help me what should I modify if I need to do `print(team.playerlist)` ? @tuned